# How to sandbox a process in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, containers, sandbox

I am working on a project where clients will be able to submit c# code snippets in the browser.

For security reasons we've decided to run the app in a container, however, users can still access the file system, thus read/create/edit files and run different processes like:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown","/s /t 0");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

While there is not much they can do in the container, they could still run some long process like mining cryptos or hit some memory limit by creating files which will impact our cloud costs.

So my question is there a way to limit the access to certain namespaces like `System.IO` and `System.Diagnostics`? Or configure the container to limit the permissions as much as possible?

We are targeting .Net Core, so AppDomains and CAS are not an option.

I know there are quite a few threads where c# sandboxing is discussed, but none of them really works for me.

Comment: Yes... you configure the container to deny filesystem and process execution access to the user that the site is running as. Which is not a .NET Core problem or concern.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, I am not sure how to implement your suggestions. Generally denying access to the file system is not an option as for certain operations the file system is still necessary. As for denying process execution, I did not find any configuration which allows you to that. Do you have any sample configuration or docs articles I could use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check [AppArmor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/), it's a Linux kernel security  that you can use to restrict the capabilities of a processes running on the host operating system.

The [Nginx example profile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/#nginx-example-profile) might be helpful to achieve what you want.